# newUser.somefunction is not a a function [Mongoose]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have made a simple signup and added a function to the database and when I try to use it I get this error - `TypeError: newUser.generateHash is not a function`. I'm new to passport and I figured to only use passport for login. I've disabled the routes to make the problem short.

user.js

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        password: String
    });

    var pollsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        pollTitle: String,
        option1: String,
        option2: String,
        option3: String,
        option4: String
    })

    userSchema.methods.generateHash = function generateHash(password) {
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    }

    userSchema.methods.validPassword = function validPassword (password) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    }


    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
    module.exports = mongoose.model('polls', pollsSchema);
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session')
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('./models/user');

var app = express();
//Connection to Database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/polls');

//Post for enviorement
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

//Using middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secretstuff',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/tmp')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

//require('./config/passport')(passport);
//configuration of app

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

//Routes
//require('./routes/dynamic.js')(app, passport);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    console.log('sdsss');
    var pattUser =  /^[a-z\S]{6,12}$/;
    var pattPass = /^[a-z\S]{8,14}$/;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var pass = req.body.password;
    var confirmpass = req.body.confirmpass;
    if(pattUser.test(username) === true && pattPass.test(pass) === true && pass === confirmpass) {
      console.log('ddddd-server');
      User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) { return err; }
        if(user) { 
          res.jsonp({message: 'username already taken'}); 
        } else {
          var newUser = new User();
          console.log(newUser.generateHash(pass));
          newUser.username = username;
          newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(pass);

          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if(err) { return err; } 
          })
          res.jsonp({message: 'You can now Log In!'});
        }
      })
    }
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Comment: Why are You exporting 2 times in your first snippet?

Comment: Hey. that worked when I removed a module.exports.Thanks! What is the correct way of exporting multiple Schema's?

Comment: either exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema); exports.Polls = mongoose.model('polls', pollsSchema) or module.exports = {User:  mongoose.model('User', userSchema), Polls: mongoose.model('polls', pollsSchema)}. You are rewriting your User export when you export your Polls model on last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannon use 'module.exports = ' more then one time. 
The second statement overwrites the first one.
If you want to export two different schemas do that:

```
module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.Polls= mongoose.model('polls', pollsSchema);
```

And then on you `server.js`

```
var schemas = require('./models/user');
var User = schemas.User;
var polls = schemas.Polls;
```